# Makefile: Run consecutive script only if the target was updated

Tags: macos, makefile, return-value, zsh

Consider the following simple `Makefile`:

```
clean:
    rm *.log *.aux *.log *.pdf *.toc *.script *.dat

summary.pdf: summary.tex
    /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=errorstopmode summary.tex
```

If `summary.tex` is unchanged, running `make summary.pdf` returns:

```
make: `summary.pdf' is up to date.
```

And error code 0.

However, I would like to display the created PDF only if it was created. The obvious choice would be `make summary.pdf  && open summary.pdf`; however, since `make` returns `0` (which means success), the PDF viewer will open the existing PDF even if it hasn't been changed.

There are many ugly ways to script this, but I wonder if I'm missing any obvious choice.

**How do I invoke a command only if `make` actually created a target?**

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way is to add the *view* command to recipe:

```
clean:
    rm *.log *.aux *.log *.pdf *.toc *.script *.dat

summary.pdf: summary.tex
    /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=errorstopmode summary.tex
    open $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to add the view command to the makefile as @Alex suggested, you could move the decision to open the file outside of make as follows:

```
summary.pdf: summary.tex
    /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=errorstopmode summary.tex
    @echo "UPDATED PDF FILE: $@"
```

And then call your makefile with the following script:

```
make | grep -q "^UPDATED PDF FILE: " && open file
```

or

```
for file in `make | sed -n "s/^UPDATED PDF FILE: \(.*\)$/\1/p"`; do
     open $file; 
done
```

for something more robust.   (sorry, not familiar with OSx, but I'm assuming you can do similar things from there).

As a general rule, you don't want to change the return value of make, as it is well documented that make returning anything but 0 implies an error.   This would confuse any scripts which rely on that behavior, and make your code non-portable.